# Confirmation MessageBox not working in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm having issues with my popup confirmation message box in my MVC project.

Basically i have the following:

```
 @foreach(document in Model.Documents)
{
   @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteDocument", "Document", new { id = 
  document.Id}, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete 
  this document"+ document.FileName +"?');", @class = "button small button 
  alert"})

}
```

As you can see above when i pass the *"+ document.FileName +"* in the onclick function the popup confirmation box is not triggered i'm not sure why its not working but when i don't include the  *"+ document.FileName +"*  like in the context below the popUp message box pops up.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteDocument", "Document", new { id = document.Id},new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this document'?');", @class = "button small button alert"})
```

What am i doing wrong? or could there be anything that i'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself i had the incorrect format is this:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteDocument", "Document", new { id = 
  document.Id},  new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this document" + document.FileName + "?')", @class = "button small button alert" })
```

Instead of this:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteDocument", "Document", new { id = 
  document.Id}, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete 
  this document"+ document.FileName +"?');", @class = "button small button 
  alert"})
```

Answer (score 0):

**use this**

```
 @foreach(var document in Model.Documents)
{
   @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteDocument", "Document", new { @id = 
  document.Id, @onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete 
  this document"+ document.FileName +"?');", @class = "button small button 
  alert"})

}
```